# how to set uneditable other EditTexts after type in one of them?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, if-statement, android-edittext

I have four EditTexts in my App

and want to become uneditable all of other 3 edittexts as soon as we write in one of them ?

how can I Achieve it ?

Comment: You should provide [minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to find help.

Comment: @EmreDalkiran... this question already is complete!

Comment: @HarshitSeksaria I meaned the code sample op is working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `TextChangedListener` to the `EditText`s and that will be triggered every time the text of the respective `EditText` changes.

You can make any `EditText` not editable, by the below code:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

So your whole code will be:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       editText2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
       editText3.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
       editText4.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {

   }
});
```

And the same code would be use for the remaining 3 `EditText`s.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add text watcher on all of the edit texts and in each watcher you need to disable other edit texts.
you need four of this watcher

```
field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // now check if text is not empty disable field 2, 3 ,4. 
   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {

   }
  });
```